# URL of existing directory does not match expected URL

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm *completely* new to SVN and I've got the tortoise client installed.  I've been instructed to download the repository into my local folder so that I can view the files and get familiar with them.

However I'm getting the following message when I select SVN Update:

> Url XXX of existing directory XXX does
>   not match the expected Url XXX

I've taken a look with the Repo-browser and can confirm that there are two folders with the same name (but differing case) and I'm expecting this is what's causing the problem, however since these aren't my files I can't make any changes to them.

It seemed to work fine until I cancelled a previous update as it had stopped responding.

Any ideas?

Comment: What I would try is follow: I resolve the conflict in name by using the repo browser. Rename one folder and update the whole project on the hard disk. Are both folders different projects, then use the option relocate. Avoiding this constallation because it will go into serious trouble if you check out this under an operating system wich is not case sensitiv like windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows simply can not handle two files/folders with the same name, different only in case.
Because Windows treats those as the same file/folder.

Which means for you: you can not checkout/update/whatever a full and complete working copy from such a repository. The only way to do that would be to switch to a Linux system with a non-case-insensitive filesystem.

Or better: tell someone to change the name of one of those files/folders.